# How to pass data to template parameter via *ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular-template, ng-template

Can we pass `[1,2,3]` to parameter `p` of template `A`
and pass `[4,5,6]` to parameter `q` of template `B` from `*ngIf`?

```
<div *ngIf="true;then A;else B"></div>

<ng-template #A let-p>p: {{p}}</ng-template>
<ng-template #B let-q>q: {{q}}</ng-template>
```

Here is my attempt but it does not work.

```
<div *ngIf="true;then A; context:{$implicit:[1,2,3]};else B;context:{$implicit:[4,5,6]}"></div>

<ng-template #A let-p>p: {{p}}</ng-template>
<ng-template #B let-q>q: {{q}}</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think with **single** ternary operator is difficult to work for your requirement.

**Approach 1: With `[ngSwitch]` + `[ngTemplateOutlet]`**

```
<div [ngSwitch]="true">
  <ng-container
    *ngSwitchCase="true"
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="A"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: [1, 2, 3] }"
  >
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container
    *ngSwitchDefault
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="B"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: [4, 5, 6] }"
  >
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

---

**Approach 2: With `[ngTemplateOutlet]` and multiple ternary operators**

```
<div>
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="true ? A : B"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: true ? [1, 2, 3] : [4, 5, 6] }"
  >
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

[Demo Apprach 1 & 2 @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tuc2ur?file=src/app/app.component.html)